# How do I access halo on column click event?

Tags: highcharts

[image: halo on click event]

How do I access the halo on click event? In my current code, I can only create an on click event to the actual column (point). I want the user to be able to click anywhere in the shaded area, rather than on the actual column.

My code below:

```
<Chart
  chart={{
  type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
          [0, '#2a2a2b'],
          [1, '#3e3e40']
        ]
      },
      plotBorderColor: '#606063'
    }}
    title={{
      text: 'Quailty Score',
      style: {
        color: '#E0E0E3',
        fontSize: '20px'
      }
    }}
    xAxis={[{
      categories: qualityScore.accountQualityScore.graphData.qualityScore,
      crosshair: true,
      gridLineColor: '#707073',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#E0E0E3'
        }
      },
      lineColor: '#707073',
      minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
      tickColor: '#707073',
      title: {
        style: {
          color: '#A0A0A3'
        }
      }
    }]}
    yAxis={[{
      min: 0,
      gridLineColor: '#707073',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#E0E0E3'
        }
      },
      lineColor: '#707073',
      minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
      tickColor: '#707073',
      title: {
        text: 'Ad Groups',
        style: {
          color: '#A0A0A3'
        }
      }
    }]}
    tooltip={{
      headerFormat: '<table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">      {series.name}: </td>' +
          '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
      style: {
        color: '#F0F0F0'
      }
    }}
    plotOptions={{
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.1,
        borderWidth: 0,
        point: {
          events: {
            click: (e) => {
              console.log(`value: ${e.point.y}`);
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          color: '#B0B0B3'
        },
        marker: {
          lineColor: '#333'
        }
      },
      boxplot: {
        fillColor: '#505053'
      },
      candlestick: {
        lineColor: 'white'
      },
      errorbar: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    }}
    series={[{
      name: 'Ad Groups',
      data: qualityScore.accountQualityScore.graphData.count
    }]}
    legend={{
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#E0E0E3'
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: '#606063'
      }
    }}
    loading={qualityScore.accountQualityScore.loading}
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this is another one that has multiple answers.

I approached by using the chart click event, like this:

```
chart: { 
  events: {
    click: function(e) {
      var xVal = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
          yVal = this.series[0].data[xVal].y;
      console.log('x: ', xVal, 'y: ', yVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Which works great for when the user clicks off of the point, but when they click on the point, the point click event overrides the chart click event.

So I had to capture the point click event as well:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: { 
    events: {
      click: function(e) {
        var xVal = e.point.x,
            yVal = e.point.y;
        console.log('x: ', xVal, 'y: ', yVal);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using both of these click events together, you can capture the same information whether the user clicks on the point, or on the crosshair area above the point.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xufekLpv/

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response with example! I didn't realize I had to add the click event to multiple locations.

Comment: I initially thought that the chart click event would be enough. There may be a way to do it without having to do it twice, but I am not sure.